# The new 16.10 google drive doesn't sync all my folders

Tags: gnome, 16.10, google-drive

I followed the tutorials to add an online account to `gnome-online-accounts`, and started syncing my google drive folder. I have two problems:

1. It takes a very long time after clicking the drive for the folders and files to populate - somewhere around 2-3 minutes.
2. Not all folders and files sync. Some folders show up but do not have all sub-files or sub-folders. The same files and folders always show up (meaning the same files and folders are missing each time), but multiple folders are missing items.

What can I do to fix this?